# how can i make a one page ror site work with all of crud functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, single-page-application, crud

so at one point this all worked and then when I came back to work on it, it stopped working. I get a no route matches err for my index page

When I check my routes I feel like they are limited, but I don't know if it has anything to do with I'm tying to do.
This from localhost3000/routes -

```
admin_packing_printers_path GET     /admin/packing_printers(.:format)       admin/packing_printers#index
                            POST    /admin/packing_printers(.:format)       admin/packing_printers#create
admin_packing_printer_path  PATCH   /admin/packing_printers/:id(.:format)   admin/packing_printers#update
                            PUT     /admin/packing_printers/:id(.:format)   admin/packing_printers#update
                            DELETE  /admin/packing_printers/:id(.:format)   admin/packing_printers#destroy
```

Funny thing is I can't find anything else from rake routes or from routes.rb, but they used to be there also.

index -

```
<% content_for(:meta_title) { 'Packing Printers' } %>

<% content_for(:title) do %>
    <div class='admin-sub-header'>
      <%= subheader_title('Packing Printers', icon: 'users') %>
    </div>
<% end %>
<div>
  <% if current_admin_user.manager %>
    <%= button_to("+ New Packing Printer", new_admin_packing_printer_path, {:class => 'btn btn-success', :method => :get}) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="widget-box">
  <%= widget_title('Packing Printers', icon: 'wrench') %>
  <div class="widget-content nopadding">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover data-table">
      <thread>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>GUID</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thread>
      <tbody>
        <% @printer = PackingPrinter.new %>
        <%= simple_form_for [:admin, @printer], method: puts do |f| %>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:guid) %></td>
          <td><%= button_to("Add New Printer", new_admin_packing_printer_path(@printer), {:class => 'btn btn-primary'}) %></td>
       <% end %>
        <tr>
          <% @printers.each do |printer| %>
          <%= simple_form_for [:admin, printer] do |f| %>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:guid) %></td>
            <td><%= button_to("Update", edit_admin_packing_printer_path(printer), {:class => 'btn btn-success', :method => puts}) %>
            <%= button_to("Delete", admin_packing_printer_path(printer),
            {:class => 'btn btn-danger', method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'  }}) %>
            </td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

controller -

```
class Admin::PackingPrintersController < AdminController
  def index
    @printers = PackingPrinter.all
  end

  def update
    @printer = PackingPrinter.find(params[:id])
    begin
      @printer.update!(packing_printer_params) if @printer.present?
    rescue => e
      flash[:errors] = "#{e}"
    end
    redirect_to action: "index"
  end

  def create
    begin
      PackingPrinter.create!(name: packing_printer_params[:name], guid: packing_printer_params[:guid])
    rescue => e
      flash[:errors] = "#{e}"
    end
    redirect_to action: "index"
  end

  def destroy
    @printer = PackingPrinter.find(packing_printer_params[:id])
    @printer.destroy
    if @printer.id?
      flash[:success] = 'Printer was deleted successfully.'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Printer was not deleted'
    end
    redirect_to action: "index"
  end

private

  def packing_printer_params
    key = params[:packing_printer] if params.keys.include?('packing_printer')
    key ||= params
    key.permit(:id, :name, :guid)
  end

end
```

Comment: Please add your `routes.rb` file to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot I had deleted a few resources from routes.rb, I need following -

```
resources :packing_printers, only: [:index, :edit, :create, :new, :update, :destroy]
```